# Inconsistent water pressure

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure

I live in a 3 story condo, built in 2012.  On public/city water.  Appears my water pressure regulator is a Wilkins 70XL, set to 50psi - checked using an Amazon water pressure tester about 6 inches above the regulator on the bottom story.

I've noticed that some times (especially early morning) water pressure will be significantly higher on the 3rd story.  During normal times, water pressure is a little on the softer end, especially on the 2nd and 3rd story.

Is this normal behavior, or an indication that my water pressure regulator is faulty and needs to be repaired or replaced?  Also, is 50psi sufficient for a 3 story condo?

Comment: Use of the water can be a factor.  A person on each floor using water(shower/toilet/dishes) at the same time and you are lucky to get water.

Comment: I've noticed the varieties in water pressure when no one else in the condo is using the water.

Comment: Usually cities have a main water pipe.  It only has so much water at a time.  I imagine you have building beside you that also get water from the main pipe.  Even a single house on a well with one inlet the water pressure will change with the number of faucets open at once.  Expecting water pressure to be consistent is not normal.

Comment: @crip659, Yeah, there's another 40+ condos in my complex.  Should I be setting the pressure regulating valve at the time of highest water pressure then?  (like 7:30am this morning had noticeably higher pressure than normal)

Comment: Pressure regulating valves are there to protect the water pipes.  Below ~80 pounds should be enough, but if not the owner of the building(the whole building), playing around with it might not be allowed or appreciated by the other people/owners.  Above 80 pounds usually not good for pipes(bursting).  If set for 50 pounds I would leave it be.

Comment: If you have (common enough feature the one you got may have it) or get a water pressure meter with peak indicating needle, leave it on for a day and see where the peak reading gets to. I assume the regulator is inside your condo, for your condo, not (as @crip659 seems to think) the whole complex. Unlikely that a 3/4" PRV would serve more than one dwelling.

Comment: That's correct, the regulator is inside my condo and only sets my own water pressure, so I can set it however I'd like.  I wouldn't mind more pressure on the upper stories, to be honest.  However, my gauge (amazon cheapie) doesn't capture peak water pressure

Comment: @Ecnerwal, While I certainly understand that the pressure coming into my pressure regulating valve can vary, I'm curious what would happen if I set my valve during a time with low pressure.  Will it exceed the 50psi reading during times of higher city pressure?  Or does the fact that I'm experiencing water pressure higher than 50psi during off-peak times indicate my pressure regulating valve is bad?

Comment: it a pressure reducing valve it can't increase the pressure.  setting it to a lower pressure may reduce the fluctuations you experience.

Comment: The main question that a peak registering gauge (or some obsolete device with a video camera recording the gauge face) would tell you is if the pressure is rising higher than you have set it, which would be a strong indicator that the valve is in need of a rebuild. You'd also be able to see (with a video) if the pressure is, at times, falling lower, which might indicate a supply pressure limitation. Ideally you'd have a pair of gauges, one before, and one after the PRV, to be sure where to assign the blame...